Python - The fitness value is oscillating up and down
I am solving a p-median problem using genetic algorithm for facility location problem. However, after running the code I found that the fitness value come out is not stable. The code is as shown below:
# Set parameters
num_demand_points = 2130
num_stations = 46
p = 10
weights = [1 for _ in range(num_demand_points)]

# Helper function to repair an individual
def repair(individual):
    while sum(individual) < p:
        idx = random.choice([i for i, x in enumerate(individual) if x == 0])
        individual[idx] = 1
    while sum(individual) > p:
        idx = random.choice([i for i, x in enumerate(individual) if x == 1])
        individual[idx] = 0
    return individual

# Generate initial population with p stations
def generate_initial_population(size):
    population = set() 
    while len(population) < size:
        individual = [0] * num_stations
        indices = list(range(num_stations))
        random.shuffle(indices)
        selected_indices = indices[:p]
        for idx in selected_indices:
            individual[idx] = 1
        population.add(tuple(individual))
    return [list(ind) for ind in population]

# Fitness Function
def fitness(individual, distance_matrix):
    total_distance = 0
    
    for demand_point_index in range(num_demand_points):
        min_distance = float('inf')
        
        for station_index in range(num_stations):
            if individual[station_index] ==1:
                min_distance = min(min_distance, distance_matrix[demand_point_index][station_index])
        total_distance += weights[demand_point_index] * min_distance
    return total_distance

# Sort fitness
def sort_fitness(population, fitnesses):
    sorted_index = np.argsort(fitnesses)
    sorted_population = [population[i] for i in sorted_index]
    sorted_fitness = [fitnesses[i] for i in sorted_index]
    print (f"Fitness: {sorted_fitness[:5]}")
    return sorted_population, sorted_fitness

# Evaluation function
def evaluation(population):
    #Calculate fitness value for each chromosome
    pop_fitness = [fitness(individual, distance_matrix) for individual in population]
    
    #Sort population by fitness
    population_sorted, fitness_sorted = sort_fitness(population, pop_fitness)
    
    return population_sorted, fitness_sorted

# Roulette Wheel Selection
def roulette_wheel_select(population, fitnesses, selection_percentage):
    num_parents = int(len(population) * selection_percentage)
    num_parents = max(num_parents, 2)
    
    # Transform fitness values for minimization
    inverted_fitness = [1 / f for f in fitnesses]
    
    # Calculate total fitness
    total_fitness = sum(inverted_fitness)
    
    # Calculate selection probabilities
    selection_probs = [f / total_fitness for f in inverted_fitness]
    
    # Perform roulette wheel selection
    cumulative_probs = [sum(selection_probs[:i+1]) for i in range(len(selection_probs))]
   
    new_population = []
    for _ in range(num_parents):
        r = random.random()
        for i, individual in enumerate(population):
            if r <= cumulative_probs[i]:
                new_population.append(individual)
                break
                
    return new_population

# Three-parent crossover function
def three_parent_crossover(parent1, parent2, parent3):
    child = []
    for i in range(len(parent1)):
        child.append(parent1[i] if parent1[i] == parent2[i] else parent3[i])
    return repair(child)

# Binary Bit-Flipping Mutation function
def bit_flip_mutate(individual, mutation_rate=0.05):
    for i in range(len(individual)):
        if random.random() < mutation_rate:
            individual[i] = 1 - individual[i]
    return repair(individual)

# Check duplicate
def check_duplicate(list1, list2):
    for i in list2:
        if list1 == i:
            return False
    return True

def termination(no_improvement_count, generation):
    #Check if best fitness has not improved for certain number generations
    if no_improvement_count == max_no_improvement:
        return False
    if generation == max_iteration:
        return False
    return True

# Run Genetic ALgorithm
# Set Parameters
population_size = 240
max_iteration = 100
selection_percentage = 0.5
crossover_rate = 0.8
mutation_rate = 0.05
max_no_improvement = 50
elitism_count = 6
    
# Generate initial population
population = generate_initial_population(population_size)
    
# Evaluation
population_sort, fitness_sort = evaluation(population)
    
generation = 0
no_improvement_count = 0

while termination(no_improvement_count, generation):
    
    #Record best fitness before this generation
    best = fitness_sort[0]
        
    # Filter the best 50% chromosome from the population
    best_50_chromosome = population_sort[:int(population_size/2)]
    best_50_fitness = fitness_sort[:int(population_size/2)]
        
    # Create new child population
    children = []
    
    # Selection
    parent_pool = roulette_wheel_select(best_50_chromosome, best_50_fitness, selection_percentage)
        
    # Crossover
    for i in range (0, 4*len(parent_pool), 1):
        # Randomly select three distinct parents
        indices = random.sample(range(len(parent_pool)), 3)
        parent1 = parent_pool[indices[0]]
        parent2 = parent_pool[indices[1]]
        parent3 = parent_pool[indices[2]]
        
        if random.random() < crossover_rate:
            child = three_parent_crossover(parent1, parent2, parent3)
            
        else:
            child = parent1
            
        # Mutation        
        mutated_child = bit_flip_mutate(child, mutation_rate)
        
            
        # check duplicate
        if check_duplicate(mutated_child, best_50_chromosome) and check_duplicate(mutated_child, children) and len(children) < int(population_size/2):
            children.append(mutated_child)
                
    
    # Combine all population
    new_population = best_50_chromosome + children 
    
    # Elitism: carry over the top individuals
    new_population[:elitism_count] = population_sort[:elitism_count]
        
    # Evaluation
    population_sort, fitness_sort = evaluation(new_population)
    
    if len(new_population) > population_size:
        population_sort = population_sort[:population_size] 
        fitness_sort = fitness_sort[:population_size]    

    best_individual, best_fitness = population_sort[0], fitness_sort[0]
    print(f"Generation {generation} - Min: {best_fitness} - CS: {population_sort[:5]} - FS : {fitness_sort[:5]} - PL:{len(children)}")
        
    # Record improvement in best fitness
    new_best = fitness_sort[0]
    if best == new_best:
        no_improvement_count+=1
    else: 
        no_improvement_count = 0
    
    generation +=1
    
print(f"Best individual: {best_individual}, Best fitness: {best_fitness}")

What I am trying to get is the decreasing answer so that the convergence graph can look like this.
enter image description here
Besides, since I will have different mutation rate and selection operators for analysis, thus for now these are fix and should not be change. Thank you.

Change these parameters based on the problem in hand: population_size, max_iteration, selection_percentage, crossover_rate, mutation_rate, max_no_improvement, elitism_count and try again. Also you need to do a code review. Dig deeper into defining a proper fitness function. Fitness function is important.
